# android - running activity within activity within tabwidget

Tags: android, android-activity, tabwidget

I have a problem. I would like to load activity from another activity which is in TabWidget but once I am using

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
```

secondActivity is loaded but it takes all screen and there are no more tabs. Is there a possibility to load secondActivity but into the active tab layout (TabWidget)?

cheers,
/Marcin

Comment: Not easilly. You might be better off using different views and a viewflipper instead of different activities

Comment: ok but is it possible to have separated activities in the view flipper or just views ?